# ¿cómo insertar varios registros a una misma tabla con laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un formulario con varios input y un botón guardar, cuando guarde necesito que haga varios insert into en mi base de datos a una misma tabla como podría hacer esto

código de mi vista

```
<form method="get" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">SELECCIONAR PLAN</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="codPlanf[]">
                                <option value="0">::SELECCIONE::</option>
                                @foreach($planes as $plan)
                                    <option value="{{$plan->codPlanA}}">{{$plan->nombrePlan}}</option>
                                @endforeach

                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                        <div class="form-group has-success"><label class="col-sm-1 control-label">PLANIFICACION</label>
                        </div>
                        @foreach($etapasPlanificacion as $etapaPlanificacion)
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-4 ">{{$etapaPlanificacion['nombre']}}</label>
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}"
                                       name="etapa{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}[]">
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                    <input placeholder="Fecha de inicio" class="form-control" type="text"
                                           onfocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date"
                                           name="fechaIni{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}[]" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input placeholder="Fecha de fin" class="form-control" type="text"
                                           onfocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date"
                                           name="fechaFin{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}[]">
                                </div>


             <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="Dias habiles" class="form-control"
                                           name="dias_habiles{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}[]">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                       @endforeach
</form>
```

esto es mi controlador, acá es donde quiero guardar mis campos

```
public function guardar(Request $request)
    {
        $i=0;

       foreach ($request as $req)

           $cronograma = new Cronograma();
        $cronograma->codPlanA = $req->codPlanA;
        $cronograma->codEtp = $req->etapa;
        $cronograma->fechaIni = $req->fechaIni;
        $cronograma->fechaFin = $req->fechaFin;
        $cronograma->dias_habiles = $req->dias_habiles;
        $i++;
        endforeach

    return redirect('auditoria/listar');
}
```

como pueden ver mis input los he puesto name="algo[]", es decir como array
esto lo recibo en el request pero no sé como hacer que guarde varios.

Answer (score 1):

Varias cosas tengo que aclarar:

1- La sentencia endforeach No se usa en la controladora, sino en las vistas por tanto tu ciclo debe ser:

```
foreach($request as $req){
  //Codigo adentro
}
```

2- Debes comprobar que tu clase Request usada como parámetro de tu action en la controladora sea esta \Illuminate\Http\Request\Request, ya sea usando al comienzo de tu archivo

```
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

O en la misma función de tu controladora

```
public function guardar(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
```

3- Para acceder a los distintos datos pasados en la solicitud y poder recorrerlos debes llamar a la función **all** de la clase Request, porque de lo contrario te lanzaría una Excepción. Es decir debe quedar de esta manera tu foreach

```
foreach ($request->all() as $req)
```

4- Debes organizar mejor la manera de nombrar tus campos en el @foreach de la vista de manera tal que puedas identificar de una misma etapa los distintos valores que el introdujo en el formulario por ejemplo algo como lo siguiente

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="exp_123[name]" value="dato1" />
<input type="text" name="exp_123[edad]" value="dato2" />
<input type="text" name="exp_123[dir]" value="dato3" />

<input type="text" name="exp_456[name]" value="dato4" />
<input type="text" name="exp_456[edad]" value="dato5" />
<input type="text" name="exp_456[dir]" value="dato6" />

<input type="text" name="exp_567[name]" value="dato7" />
<input type="text" name="exp_567[edad]" value="dato8" />
<input type="text" name="exp_567[dir]" value="dato9" />

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" />
</form>
```

De manera tal que cuando accedas a lo enviado lo tengas organizado de la siguiente manera:

```
 Array
(
  [exp_123] => Array
    (
        [name] => dato1
        [edad] => dato2
        [dir] => dato3
    )

[exp_456] => Array
    (
        [name] => dato4
        [edad] => dato5
        [dir] => dato6
    )

[exp_567] => Array
    (
        [name] => dato7
        [edad] => dato8
        [dir] => dato9
    )

[enviar] => Enviar
)
```

Ahora en tu ejemplo quedaría tu html de esta manera:

```
<form method="get" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">SELECCIONAR PLAN</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="codPlanf">
            <option value="0">::SELECCIONE::</option>
            @foreach($planes as $plan)
                <option value="{{$plan->codPlanA}}">{{$plan->nombrePlan}}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
    <div class="form-group has-success"><label class="col-sm-1 control-label">PLANIFICACION</label>
    </div>
    @foreach($etapasPlanificacion as $etapaPlanificacion)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 ">{{$etapaPlanificacion['nombre']}}</label>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}"
                       name="data_{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}[etapa]">
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                    <input placeholder="Fecha de inicio" class="form-control" type="text"
                           onfocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date"
                           name="data_{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}[fechaIni]" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input placeholder="Fecha de fin" class="form-control" type="text"
                           onfocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date"
                           name="data_{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}[fechaFin]">
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Dias habiles" class="form-control"
                        name="data_{{$etapaPlanificacion['codEtp']}}[dias_habiles]">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</form>
```

Cabe aclarar que en tu código original no hay ningún botón con la función de enviar, no se si no lo copiastes a la hora de preguntar o haces la operación desde otra vía. Si no lo tenias debes agregarlo antes de la etiqueta de cierre de form, algo como esto:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Ahora en la parte de la controladora si tienes en tu modelo **Cronograma.php** establecida la propiedad $fillable con los mismos atributos que planeas utilizar al llenar el modelo, puedes hacerlo mucho más simple

Si tienes esto en tu modelo:

```
protected $fillable = ['codPlanA', 'codEtp', 'fechaIni', 'fechaFin', 'dias_habiles'];
```

Tu controladora quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public function guardar(Request $request)
{
   foreach ($request->all() as $req){
       Cronograma::create([
           'codPlanA'   => $req['codPlanf'],
           'codEtp'     => $req['etapa'],
           'fechaIni'   => $req['fechaIni'],
           'fechaFin'   => $req['fechaFin'],
           'dias_habiles'   => $req['dias_habiles']
       ]);
   }
    return redirect('auditoria/listar');
}
```

Ahora si no tienes establecida la propiedad $fillable como te indiqué puedes hacerlo casi como mismo lo tenias

```
public function guardar(Request $request)
{
   foreach ($request->all() as $req){
        $cronograma = new Cronograma();
        $cronograma->codPlanA = $req['codPlanf'];
        $cronograma->codEtp = $req['etapa'];
        $cronograma->fechaIni = $req['fechaIni'];
        $cronograma->fechaFin = $req['fechaFin'];
        $cronograma->dias_habiles = $req['dias_habiles'];
        $cronograma->save();
   }

    return redirect('auditoria/listar');
}
```

Espero que te halla servido de algo. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método insert (acepta un array como parámetro), sin embargo hasta donde recuerdo debes generar también los timestamps en caso que los utilice tu modelo:

```
$cronogramas = [];
foreach ($request as $req) {
    $cronograma['codPlanA'] = $req->codPlanA;
    $cronograma['codEtp'] = $req->etapa;
    // ... los demás campos
    // timestamp: $cronograma['created_at'] =  now(); <-- Laravel 5.5

    $cronogramas[] = $cronograma;
}

Cronograma::insert($cronogramas);
```

Una pequeña observación y es que Laravel es PSR-2, por lo cual tu código también debería serlo, por favor revisa este enlace: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/